# Defining a function in Mathematica without functional form

Tags: function-construction

I am trying to define a function $H(s)$ in Mathematica, but the only restrictions/information on this function are that it is a concave and increasing in $s$, which is defined over the interval $[0,S_{\text{max}}]$. Further, $H(s=0)=0$ and $H(s>0)=h>0$. Since the exact form isn't specified, I'm not sure how to use the `:=` command here.

Comment: There isn't a way to do this without assuming some kind of form. I think it would help to know *why* you needed to define such an abstract function.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me. It is not answerable unless you explain what you are _actually_ trying to do.

Comment: *Mathematica* is an expression rewriting system. `:=` simply tells it to rewrite anything that matches the left hand side using the right hand side.

Comment: Is h a constant? If yes, H is a step function:  H= Piecewise[{{h, # > 0}}, 0] & where h is the constant value.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this?

```
H[0] = 0;
H[x_] := ConditionalExpression[h[x], h[x] > 0 && x > 0];
(* Alternatively, you can do *)
H[x_] := ConditionalExpression[#, # > 0 && x > 0] &@h[x];
```

Let's try this with:

```
h[x_] = (x + 5)(x - 5);
```

There are 5 possible cases to test:

$H(s = 0)$

```
H[0] (* Outputs 0 *)
```

$H(s < 0) = h > 0$

```
H[-6] (* Outputs Undefined *)
```

$H(s < 0) = h \leq 0$

```
H[-1] (* Outputs Undefined *)
H[-5] (* Outputs Undefined *)
```

$H(s > 0) = h \leq 0$

```
H[1] (* Outputs Undefined *)
H[5] (* Outputs Undefined *)
```

$H(s > 0) = h > 0$

```
H[6] (* Outputs 11 *)
```

##### Unknown $h(x)$

If you don't have a definition for $h(x)$, you could define an additional function which simplifies the conditional statement depending on the constraints on $h(x)$ by using `Assumptions`:

```
f[x_] := Simplify[H[x]];
f[x_, ineq_] := Simplify[H[x], Assumptions -> {ineq /. h -> h[x]}];
```

Test cases:

$H(s = 0)$

```
f[0] (* Outputs 0 *)
f[7] (* Outputs unsimplified conditional expression: ConditionalExpression[h[7], h[7] > 0] *)
```

$H(s < 0) = h > 0$

```
f[-6, h > 0] (* Outputs Undefined *)
f[-6, h > 7] (* Outputs Undefined *)
```

$H(s < 0) = h \leq 0$

```
f[-1, h <= 0] (* Outputs Undefined *)
f[-5, h <= 0]  (* Outputs Undefined *)
f[-5, -3 < h < -1]  (* Outputs Undefined *)
```

$H(s > 0) = h \leq 0$

```
f[1, h <= 0]  (* Outputs Undefined *)
f[5, h <= 0] (* Outputs Undefined *)
f[5, -3 < h < -1] (* Outputs Undefined *)
```

$H(s > 0) = h > 0$

```
f[6, h > 0] (* Outputs h[6] *)
f[6, h > 7] (* Outputs h[6] *)
```